# Imagemagick resize images dynamically

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-manipulation, image-resizing

I have created a App wehere the user can upload an Image and choose a region to crop. Afterward the image should be resized and cropped with the chosen coordinates.

The problem is, that those image are printed afterwards, so the quality should be as close to the original image as possible(without artifacts, or visible blur).

Anyway resizing causes a loss of quality and using unsharpmask() after resizing makes it a lot better, but it still differs from image to image.

Oh and sometimes the colours don't even match with the original :(

I know this function's parameters depend on things like the size and saturation of the image, but is there any way to calculate the best parameters?

Here's what I have so far:

```
 $origPath = "ThePathToTheFileOnTheServer.jpg";

 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],$origPath);

 $img = new Imagick();

 $file_handle_for_viewing_image = fopen($origPath, 'a+');

 $img->readImageFile($file_handle_for_viewing_image);

 fclose($file_handle_for_viewing_image);

 $img->setImageFormat('jpg');
 $img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
 $img->setImageCompressionQuality(100); 
 $img->resizeImage ( 0, $targ_h,  Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
 $img->unsharpMaskImage(0 , 0.5 , 1 , 0.05); 
 $img->cropImage($targ_w, $targ_h, $xPos, 0);                    

 $newimg = new Imagick();
 $newimg->newImage($targ_w,$targ_h,new ImagickPixel('white'));
 $newimg->setImageFormat('jpg');
 $newimg->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
 $newimg->setImageCompressionQuality(100); 
 $newimg->compositeImage($img,Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,0,0);
 $newimg->writeImage("TheNewImage.jpg");
```

It does what it should, but can I somehow calculate the parameters of $img->unsharpMaskImage(0 , 0.5 , 1 , 0.05); to fix the current Image?

Thanks for your help!

Here's an example:

original:

[image: original]

after resize:

[image: after resize]

Answer (score 0):

You could try resizing in the `Lab` colourspace and then converting back to sRGB afterwards. At the command-line, that would be

```
convert input.jpg -colorspace Lab -resize ... -colorspace sRGB result.jpg
```